# Remove side drawer from a particular page

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I have used the SideDrawer template from the Drawer Navigation template. After adding my own page (Login), the side drawer is still visible, although no hamburger icon, I can still drag out the side drawer from the left of the screen, even though my page was built from scratch with no reference to the side drawer code.

How do I disconnect the side drawer from a particular page is javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are on the login page or any page you don't want the Drawer to be shown via gestures, disable it by setting [gesturesEnabled](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/radsidedrawer#gesturesenabled) property to `false`, once logged in or whenever you want the gesture to work back, just set the value back to `true`.

Comment: How do I address the sideDrawer on another page in Javascript so I can set this boolean.

Comment: Use getViewById on frame.

Comment: `var sideDrawer = args.object.page.getViewById("sideDrawer");
    sideDrawer.gesturesEnabled = false;`  'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'sideDrawer.gesturesEnabled = false')

Comment: @FrankNicklin Without knowing your app navigation / view hierarchy we will not be able to help you much. We have to know how many frames you have, which frame RadSideDrawer is placed at. Just a wild guess, try `var sideDrawer = args.object.page.frame.getViewById("sideDrawer"); `

Answer (score 1):

OK, resolved. For anyone else

`   const app= require("tns-core-modules/application");

```
exports.onNavigatingTo = function (args){
const sideDrawer = app.getRootView();
sideDrawer.gesturesEnabled = false;
```

}
`